# SQL Server : split string with ',' DELIMITER - Table Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

SOLVED

I need to parse and split string that comes to table function as parameter as this:

```
'125','369','125' etc.
```

Now final split should then look like this:

```
125
369
125
```

However, I cannot do ',' since SQL will think it is another parameter, so when I pass string into function I have to do it like this with escape sequence:

Where first parameter is string to split and second parameter is where to split it.

However, the result is:

```
051','052','053
```

instead of

```
125
369
125
```

I think this has to do more with SQL Server having problems with '' escape sequence rather than function code itself.

FU

Comment: `SPLIT_MY_STRING` *is* most likely the problem. Either it expects split by a single character, or it's not handling `'` properly. Seriously, you're blaming MS SQL before checking your code? :D

Comment: My code worked before it was used for a year maybe :D It was splitting strings like okay like this '120,136,950' and parameter where to split the string was just ',' -> which means I wanna split string where comma is located.                                                                                                                        And SPLIT_MY_STRING expects the parameter I passed it. I designed the function so I know it works okay :D But yeah I think escape sequence is making problems there.

Comment: Don't use `'` in your string. `'1,2,3,4,5'` should be fine whereas `''1','2','3''` won't work. You would have to change your function to deal with the additional `'`.

Comment: But ''1','2','3'' will not work :) because it will take every number as separate parameter so SELECT * FROM SPLIT_MY_STRING(''1','2','3'', ''',''') will be interpreted as SELECT * FROM SPLIT_MY_STRING(param1,param2,param3, param4WhereToSplit) But function takes only 2 parameters -> string to split and where to split it.

Comment: @user3741301 It worked before *without the apostrophes*. So it was not tested or designed to work with them. Escaping works fine in MS SQL, and it's easy to get rid of it completely anyway (parameters don't need escaping, for example). Like this, your question doesn't show the problem at all - add the `SPLIT_MY_STRING` function or close the question :)

Comment: Okay function added. Btw it has to work with apostrophes around comma. Client requires it and that is parameter string that will enter the function.

Comment: Why do you want to split strings in the first place? You can use table valued parameters to pass multiple values to a stored procedure/parameterized query.

Comment: Also note that the original input string *is* `051','052','053` instead of `'051','052','053'`. You missed the quotes at the start and end of the string. Does your function work if you fix the typo?

Comment: I also suggest [Split strings the right way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and  [Split strings: Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql). Many options, much simpler and more performant than the current attempt. Nothing beats TVPs though

Comment: @user3741301 If it's solved, you should accept an answer or make a new answer to this question stating how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create function dbo.split_my_string (@clob_in varchar(max), @delimiter varchar(10)) 
return @SplitValues table (
      pos int not null
    , data varchar(max) not null
)
as
begin

declare @x xml;

set @x = cast ('<x>' + replace (@clob_in, @delimiter, '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml);

insert into @SplitValues (pos, data)
select row_number() over(order by (select 1))
    , x.x.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    --, replace (x.x.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), '''', '')
from @x.nodes('x')x(x);

return
end
```

You can replace apostrophes if you want. See the commented string.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't want to change your function code. Also, I don't know why you want to embed the escape sequence into the data.

**Here is a simple fix which may help,**

```
SELECT * 
FROM SPLIT_MY_STRING(REPLACE('125'',''369'',''125','''',''), REPLACE(''',''','''',''))
```

use replace in your function call to get the desired result.

[Fiddler help here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c3f4/1)

Answer (score -1):

If input data of `125,369,125` works, but now you are getting `'125','369','125'` and it doesn't work, then there is no need to worry about escaping anything or messing with the delimiter. Just cleanse the data before passing it in. In this case it is a simple matter of removing all single-quotes from the input string:

```sql
REPLACE(@InputCSV, '''', '')
```

And that is used as follows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SPLIT_MY_STRING(REPLACE(@InputCSV, '''', ''), ',');
```